# How to take screenshot of entire page in IE 7 using any online tool?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, screenshot, internet-explorer-7

How to take screenshot of entire page in IE 7 using any online tool, or if is there any offline tool then it should be portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt+print screen - will take a screen shot of active windows
[SuperScreenshot](http://superscreenshot.com/) - enter a URL and it will taker a screen shot of that webpage

Comment: Superscreenshot looks like it's out of commission. It's a link farm page now.

Answer (score 0):

alt+print screen will take a screenshot of the currently selected window. This works for IE as well as any other program

Answer (score 0):

Control + Print Screen: Take a screenshot of your entire Desktop.
Alt + Print Screen    : Take a screenshot of the active window.

After I do either, I paste the image in to Paint.NET to edit and save.