# website snapshot saved as a png

Tags: website

I once came across a utility program which can capture a snapshot of a website and save the full page as a png image file. Too bad I forget the name of it. Anyone helps?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take screenshot of entire page in IE 7 using any online tool?](http://superuser.com/questions/86846/how-to-take-screenshot-of-entire-page-in-ie-7-using-any-online-tool)

Comment: @ChrisF I use FireFox and Safari

Answer (score 3):

platform independent tool: '[cutycapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)':

```
CutyCapt is a small cross-platform command-line utility to 
capture WebKit's rendering of a web page into a variety of 
vector and bitmap formats, including SVG, PDF, PS, PNG, JPEG, 
TIFF, GIF, and BMP.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp), though it does a lot more than you need.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have several options for you, but just to throw it into the mix: Your OS probably provides a way to do this.

For instance, on either Windows or Linux (if you're using Gnome or a recent version of KDE) you'd press Alt+PrtScr to copy the active window's image to the clipboard (or just PrtScr to capture the entire desktop, but you said you just wanted the web page). Then paste it into (insert your favorite picture editor here) and save as PNG, optionally cropping out the browser chrome.

[This page](http://digitalmedia.oreilly.com/2006/01/01/mac-os-x-screenshot-secrets.html) discusses the screenshot features built into Mac OS X. (Command+Control+Shift+3 copies the entire screen to the clipboard, but you have several other options.)

Comment: This only gets the visible portion of the web page. If it's longer than the height of the screen you'll be missing some data.

Comment: @ChrisF: Indeed yes, and I should have highlighted that, thanks. Mostly listed this as an option for those situations where for whatever reason, using Screengrab or the other alternatives isn't convenient.

Answer (score 0):

[FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648/)

> FireShot creates screenshots of web pages entirely.
>
> The captures can be quickly annotated and:
>
> - Uploaded to Facebook, Picasa, Flickr, ..
> - Saved to disk as PNG/GIF/JPEG/BMP
> - Copied to clipboard
> - Printed
> - E-Mailed
> - Exported to e

xternal editor

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a standalone application then it might be [SiteShorter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Awesome Screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well you got bunch of answers but I would like to suggest you one more option for you.

> [Maxthon 3](http://www.maxthon.com/mx3/)

A power-packed browser which has some features that you'll definitely fall in love.

`Maxthon Snapshot` is among these features, you can check [this video](http://youtu.be/uZFXVmLRFWI) for How to Use it.

[Here](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/04/16/six-maxthon-features-that-you-may-find-useful/) are 6 other important features.

The best thing is you *don't* need to install extra plugins/exensions for these features that also causes slowliness of a browser, these are in-built in Maxthon. [Here is a review](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnmrcBeFfLA).

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE 2021: This plugin is not supported any more

I'm using the [Pearl Crescent Screen Saver](http://pearlcrescent.com/products/pagesaver/) Firefox add-on. The basic edition is free.

Comment: The site states: “This classic Page Saver extension is not compatible with Firefox 57 or newer.”

Comment: 11 yeras ago this was no problem yet ;-)